# Using F# type providers in tests

Tags: testing, f#, type-providers

I'm creating a class library with integration tests. I'm using combination of FsCheck and xUnit here. Tests are supposed to run queries on the database to verify an output. I'm using FSharp.Data.TypeProviders with System.Data.Linq (so Linq2Sql type provider) to access the database - type provider is defined inside test class library itself.

However when I'm trying to build a project, I'm getting a **Static linking may not use assembly that targets different profile.** error. Class library, where tests are located is targeting .NET Framework 4.5 (FSharp runtime 4.4.0). I've also set binding redirects for FSharp.Core assembly, however this doesn't change anything.